# What does "a dramatic annual shrub" mean?

Tags: meaning

From page 15 of [*Wicked Plants: The Weed That Killed Lincoln's Mother and Other Botanical Atrocities*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0pak4RWkdAwC&pg=PA15&dq=%22Castor+bean+is+a+dramatic+annual+or+tender+perennial+shrub+with+deeply+lobed+leaves,+prickly+seedpods,+and+large,+speckled+seeds%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY-dyn5cTsAhUOvJ4KHYo4D-MQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Castor%20bean%20is%20a%20dramatic%20annual%20or%20tender%20perennial%20shrub%20with%20deeply%20lobed%20leaves%2C%20prickly%20seedpods%2C%20and%20large%2C%20speckled%20seeds%22&f=false),

> Castor bean is a dramatic annual or tender perennial shrub with deeply lobed leaves, prickly seedpods, and large, speckled seeds.

I can understand that "tender perennial shrub" means "live for many years, that is not winter hardy", but I don't know the meaning of "dramatic" in the above sentence.

What does "a dramatic annual shrub" mean?

Comment: Possibly  because it erupts with many shoots and flowers in  a particular season...the castor weed that I know grows very high in certain times of the year, depending on seasonal supply of  water. //Hope you are not planning on poisoning anyone haha.

Comment: @Cascabel is probably right.  Assuming 'dramatic' is not a technical horticultural term.

Comment: The shrub is fond of quoting Shakespeare.

Comment: Shrubs have social-media accounts now? (what if someone wired sensors into the shrub then put an AI frontend on it)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> dramatic = "very sudden or **noticeable**, or full of action and excitement"
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dramatic)

I emphasis *noticeable* because plant lovers like a plant to be noticeable for its colour or form. And the castor bean plant (*Ricinus communis*) is certainly noticeable for both colour and form. Being either an annual grown from seed or grown as a perennial, it may confidently be described as a *dramatic* annual or tender perennial shrub.

In the comments, richardb adds:

> It should be parsed as dramatic (annual or tender perennial) shrub,
> not (dramatic annual) or (tender perennial) shrub

[image: ![Ricinus communis]

Comment: Great visual to illustrate how 'dramatic' this plant is.

Comment: Just to note that it should be parsed as dramatic (annual or tender perennial) shrub, not (dramatic annual) or (tender perennial) shrub. I suspect that may be part of OPs confusion.

Comment: The Castor plant can take a light frost at night, but will die when exposed to more severe frost and/or a several day long frost period. Depending on where you are in the world it is a perennial or an annual plant. If perennial the shrub can grow over 5 meters high. It is originally from the Middle East. It Is used as a garden plant all over the world and has become an invasive weed in some countries around the Mediterranean and in the southern states of the USA.

Comment: @richardb that deserves to be an answer on its own. Given the title and quoting in the question it is clearly the root of the confusion.